# Text filtering with patterns using sed/awk or any other way on Linux

Tags: awk, sed

Input (not specific size)

```
w23r.abc:eg-1/23-we34.abc:eg-2/43 we4r.abc:eg-2/25-w5wr.abc:eg-1/63 wewr.abc:eg-6/23-45wr.abc:eg-3/24
```

Desired output

```
w23r.abc:eg-1/23
we4r.abc:eg-2/25
wewr.abc:eg-6/23
```

How can I achieve the above using sed/awk or other text editing tools on Linux?

```
echo w23r.abc:eg-1/23-we34.abc:eg-2/43 we4r.abc:eg-2/25-w5wr.abc:eg-1/63 wewr.abc:eg-6/23-45wr.abc:eg-3/24 | tr ' ' '\n' | cut -d- -f3-
we34.abc:eg-2/43
w5wr.abc:eg-1/63
45wr.abc:eg-3/24
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO we do encourage users to add their efforts in form of code in their post, so kindly do so.Also please do mention what is the way/logic to get the expected  output as its not clear as of now.

Comment: for LINE in $(cat input); do echo $LINE|cut -c 1-16;done
will work with not large input (limited by command line length usually 4kb-32kb)

Comment: @Saboteur: Please wait with suggestions until Mercy has completed what he has tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU awk:

```
awk '{print $1,$2}' FS='-' RS=' ' OFS='-' file
```

> `FS`: input field separator
>
> `RS`: input record separator, by default a newline
>
> `OFS`: output field separator

Output:

```
w23r.abc:eg-1/23
we4r.abc:eg-2/25
wewr.abc:eg-6/23
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: Thank you Cyrus, this works great, is there a way to achieve the same result with sed as well?

Comment: With two `sed`: `sed 's/ /\n/g' file | sed 's/-[^-]*-[^-]*$//'`